# Get all possible key and values from select

Tags: php

### Note: I'm not interested in how I can parse anything into HTML. I already know that. In this scenario I'm extracting the HTML from a site, and I try to find the best way to make an array of all the different keys and values multiple selects can produce.

I'm trying to convert pages with `<select><option>` where I fetch `name=""` and `value=""` in order to get the value. This data will be transferred to an array:

```
<select name="example">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

would give:

```
array(array('example' => 1),
      array('example' => 2),
      array('example' => 3))
```

However, in my case there can be multiple `<select>`, so I need some logic to take these values and create all possible combinations in that array. I wish to be getting these as an array with 4 arrays with 2 same keys but different values:

```
<select name="example">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="second">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Would become:

```
array(array('example' => 1,
            'second'  => 1),
      array('example' => 1,
            'second'  => 2),
      array('example' => 2,
            'second'  => 1),
      array('example' => 2,
            'second'  => 2))
```

What method in php would be more ideal to create these arrays? Only way I can think of are several loops in each other. I want this solution to be scalable and work with as many `<select>` as possible.

Comment: Use `<select name="example[]">` - notice the `[]`. It's an array. See answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/3533134/1415724 based on the same.

Comment: I wish to extract from `<select>`, not create html.

Comment: Ok, you need a GET with an array and possibly a `foreach`, least that's what I think. Wait for other responses. ;-)

Comment: are you trying to get all combinations of all elements of Select?

Comment: Have a look at this, might be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442781/1415724

Comment: do you need to parse the HTML of the page to get the select values or do you already have the select name's and a list of values associated with each name?

Comment: See [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320681/multidimensional-array-how-to-get-specific-values-from-sub-array) **and answers** on that page. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone understood my problem. I've updated the question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just combine the keys like this?

```
$buildqueryarray=array();
$buildqueryarray[]=$_POST['example1'];
$buildqueryarray[]=$_POST['example2'];
$buildqueryarray[]=$_POST['example3'];
$buildqueryarray[]=$_POST['example4'];

$query="";
foreach($buildqueryarray as $k=>$v){
   $query=$k."=".$v."&";
}

$query=substr($query,0,-1);
```

Then you have in the end your query build in dependence of the given $_POST requests. You just have to add these to the buildqueryarray, since I don't know which $_POST Fields are existent

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to simply change `example` to `example[]` and `second` to `second[]`. Once there, you can do this:

```
$array = array();
$select1 = $_POST['example'];
$select2 = $_POST['second'];
array_push($array, ["example" => $select1[0], "second" => $select2[0]]);
array_push($array, ["example" => $select1[1], "second" => $select2[0]]);
array_push($array, ["example" => $select1[0], "second" => $select2[1]]);
array_push($array, ["example" => $select1[1], "second" => $select2[1]]);
```

The array `$array` will now contain exactly what you wanted it to.

To get the actual combinations, though, you can use the Math_Combinatorics class, as seen in this link:

http://pyrus.sourceforge.net/Math_Combinatorics.html

You would do something like this:

```
$combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;
$a = $combinatorics->combinations(array(
    "example" => 2,
    "second" => 2,
    ), 2);
```

`$a` will now contain x arrays, each consisting of a unique two number combination of whatever you numbers you input. You can then use those for your indexes. Simply include the indexes of that array in place of the 0's and 1's I put in the hard-coded verson.